# Bootstrap 5 aligning image inside a column to the bottom

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-5

I want to ask a question about aligning an image inside of a column to the bottom in Bootstrap 5.

Below is a HTML snippet using Bootstrap 5's CDN to create two columns, each containing an image of London, with `img-fluid` attached to get `max-width:100%` and `height: auto`:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Column img align-bottom demo</title>
        <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-EVSTQN3/azprG1Anm3QDgpJLIm9Nao0Yz1ztcQTwFspd3yD65VohhpuuCOmLASjC" crossorigin="anonymous">
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="container">
            <h2>Column img align-bottom demo</h2>
            <div class="row g-2">
                <div class="col-md border">
                    <img src="https://static.homesandproperty.co.uk/s3fs-public/thumbnails/image/2020/11/19/10/HotNotGoodLuckHope.jpg?width=990&auto=webp&quality=75&crop=968%3A645%2Csmart" class="img-fluid">
                </div>
                <div class="col-md border">
                    <img src="https://london.ac.uk/sites/default/files/styles/max_1300x1300/public/2018-10/london-aerial-cityscape-river-thames_1.jpg?itok=6LenFxuz" class="img-fluid" alt="">
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-MrcW6ZMFYlzcLA8Nl+NtUVF0sA7MsXsP1UyJoMp4YLEuNSfAP+JcXn/tWtIaxVXM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</html>
```

As you can see, the right hand side photo is aligned to the top of the column whereas I want it to be aligned to the *bottom* of the column.

[image: Screenshot showing RHS aligned to the top of the column, rather than the bottom]

I have tried the following solution via the [Bootstrap Vertical Align Documentation](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/utilities/vertical-align/) by adding `align-bottom` to the image class itself (images sourced on a Creative Commons licence for educational purposes):

```
<div class="col-md border">
    <img src="https://london.ac.uk/sites/default/files/styles/max_1300x1300/public/2018-10/london-aerial-cityscape-river-thames_1.jpg?itok=6LenFxuz" class="img-fluid align-bottom" alt="">
</div>
```

but this does not work.

How can I push the right-hand side image to align it to the bottom of the parent div?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `align-self-end` on the column...

```
<div class="container">
    <h2>Column img align-bottom demo</h2>
    <div class="row g-2">
        <div class="col-md border">
            <img src="https://static.homesandproperty.co.uk/s3fs-public/thumbnails/image/2020/11/19/10/HotNotGoodLuckHope.jpg?width=990&auto=webp&quality=75&crop=968%3A645%2Csmart" class="img-fluid">
        </div>
        <div class="col-md border align-self-end">
            <img src="https://london.ac.uk/sites/default/files/styles/max_1300x1300/public/2018-10/london-aerial-cityscape-river-thames_1.jpg?itok=6LenFxuz" class="img-fluid" alt="">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

https://codeply.com/p/WOLEhJvtqV

Comment: How to make col to take same width as it's adjacent col div. In this case col is taking height of the img.